# JDK 1.8 on Linux missing JNI include file

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, java-8, header-files

I am trying to compile the following project:

```
https://github.com/entropia/libsocket-can-java
```

I always get this error message? Does anyone know how to fix it, is it possibly a bug in JDK 1.8.0.11 on Linux (x64 Debian Wheezy)?

```
In file included from jni/de_entropia_can_CanSocket.h:2:0,
             from jni/cansocket.cpp:23:
/opt/jdk1.8.0_11/include/jni.h:45:20: fatal error: jni_md.h: No such file or directory
#include "jni_md.h"
                ^
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems so. `#include "jni_md.h"` would include the file in the same directory as `jni.h`, but it is placed in `linux` folder.

In previous JDK versions it seems that file and another were place in `include/linux` folder, but there are symlinks to both files in `include`.

So you can just create symlinks to both files:

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/jdk1.8.0_11/include/linux/jni_md.h /opt/jdk1.8.0_11/include/jni_md.h
$ sudo ln -s /opt/jdk1.8.0_11/include/linux/jawt_md.h /opt/jdk1.8.0_11/include/jawt_md.h
```

#### Edit

As stated in the comments by Absurd-Mind and Mikkel, there is also the option to add that path to the makefile compiler options:

```
-I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux/
```

Comment: i already found this too,, thank you anyway.. seems to be kind of BUG!!! isnt it??

Comment: And it worked? Yes it seems, in previous JDK versions those files are present in `linux` directory but there are symlinks to each file in the `include` folder. Will include that info in the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add `-I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux/` to the compiler option?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind I don't think so. You would have to remember that for each time you would need to compile something needing JNI. This will make it work anytime. Of course if you don't have root access, that would be a better option.

Comment: I agree with @Absurd-Mind. By adding the include option to the makefile, this configuration will be persisted in source control along with the rest of the source code. Otherwise you would have to remember to create the symlinks every time you check out the code on a new machine.

Comment: @Mikkel It depends of your target. If you just want to use a computer, creating the symlinks is better because it will make any project that needs those files work. To get the same effect with the makefile option, you will need to add that to every project you need to work on that machine. But if you just want to compile a project in multiple machines then yes, changing the makefile is a better option. Will add it to the answer

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a bug. The correct way to solve this issue is to provide `-I${JAVA_HOME}/include  -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux` compiler options. This way your build scripts remain portable.

The OP is facing the problem on Linux, but if anybody is facing this problem on windows, please add following compiler options.

`-I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32"`
where JAVA_HOME points to your JDK installation directory, usually `'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.{7|8}.{}_{xx}'`

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that there are more than one `JDK` that have been deployed, and the one that is linked to `$JAVA_HOME` is not the correct one. You need to update `$JAVA_HOME` to that that contains the `jni_md.h` file.