# Building Java interface for Open MPI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, mpi, javac, openmpi

I am trying to build the Java interface for Open MPI, using the instructions on [this page](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=java).

Once I extracted and navigated to the `openmpi-1.8.7` directory, I entered

```
./configure --enable-mpi-java
```

which returned

```
*** Java compiler
checking OSX locations... not found
checking Linux locations... not found
checking Solaris locations... not found
checking Java support available... no

*** Java MPI bindings
checking if want Java bindings... yes
configure: WARNING: Java bindings requested but no Java support found
configure: error: cannot continue
```

So I tried

```
./configure --enable-mpi-java --with-jdk-bindir=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin --with-jdk-headers=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/includecc
```

which returned

```
*** Java compiler
checking --with-jdk-bindir value... sanity check ok (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin)
checking --with-jdk-headers value... sanity check ok (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/include)
checking for javac... /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
checking for javah... /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javah
checking for jar... /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jar
checking jni.h usability... no
checking jni.h presence... no
checking for jni.h... no
checking Java support available... no

*** Java MPI bindings
checking if want Java bindings... yes
configure: WARNING: Java bindings requested but no Java support found
configure: error: cannot continue
```

I checked to see that the `javac`, `javah`, `jar`, and `jni.h` files are indeed in the `bin` and `include` folders under

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Why is the build not working? I tried searching the log file but couldn't find the issue.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996017/jdk-1-8-on-linux-missing-include-file

Comment: In 'config.log', you can see the precise test code that failed.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical issue, even though I have jdk7 and jdk7 on my Macbook, so it worked just by simply running this.:

```
./configure --enable-mpi-java
```

My jdk is under here:

```
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk1.7.0_79.jdk jdk1.8.0_91.jdk
```

Are you sure it's jdk6+ that you have? Not an older version and not just jre? What does `javac -version` say?

Answer (score 0):

Following command worked when building with Oracle Java 8

```
./configure --enable-mpi-java --with-jdk-bindir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin --with-jdk-headers=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include
```